# Applying a Paragraph Style to a threaded text frame

Tags: adobe-indesign, paragraph-styles, object-styles

When an Object Style that contains a Paragraph Style is applied to a text frame that is threaded, the Paragraph Style is not applied. This is expected behavior. Is there any way around this, or an alternative method in which I can apply a Paragraph Style to a single text frame within a thread (i.e. any text that passes through this frame will dynamically undergo said change)?